# Selecting a single jQuery item of a specific class to animate

Tags: jquery

I have multiple divs assigned a class called projectContainer, which essentially makes each div a certain size and sets the background to white. I want to be able to, when hovering over any of the divs of that class, animate THAT SPECIFIC div. The following code will animate everything with that class, changing the colour from white to red when hovered on:

```
$(".projectContainer").hover(function(){
 $(".projectContainer").animate({
   backgroundColor:'rgb(189,29,54)'},100);
},
function(){
 $(".projectContainer").animate({
   backgroundColor:'#FFF'},100);
});
```

Through my rudimentary knowledge of jQuery, I figured something like this would allow me to accomplish what I need.

```
$(*.projectContainer).hover(function(){
 $(this.id).animate({
   backgroundColor:'rgb(189,29,54)'},100);
},
function(){
 $(this.id).animate({
   backgroundColor:'#FFF'},100);
});
```

All jQuery code is placed in the document's head. I could make it work easily if I assigned each div an id and manually coded the animation for each id, but I'd like it to work automatically if I add more divs of this class. I feel that something like this could also work if placed IN the actual divs, but I want to keep it simpler by just having the single function in the head, obviously.

Comment: Your approach is correct, what you need to do is just use "this"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$(.projectContainer).hover(function(){
 $(this).animate({
   backgroundColor:'rgb(189,29,54)'},100);
},
function(){
 $(this).animate({
   backgroundColor:'#FFF'},100);
});
```

Comment: AWESOME, works, I swear that was one of the combinations I had tried. Thanks a lot.